# 改行やインデントを含む文字列をexecする方法

Tags: python

Pythonで以下のようなコードを書いてみて、一応正しく実行されたのですが
改行やインデント、変数を含む文字列をexecする場合、このような書き方で良いのでしょうか。
それとも、もっと良い書き方がありますでしょうか？

```
test_str = ''
for i in range(10):
    test_str += 'i = '+str(i) + '\n'
    test_str += 'if i%2==0:'+ '\n'
    test_str += '   if i%3==0:'+ '\n'
    test_str += '      print("'+str(i)+'")'+ '\n'
exec(test_str)
```

上記のコードは、0から9までの値をforループで回して
2で割り切れる数かつ3で割り切れる数をprintするだけの内容です。
if文にandを使っていないのは、2段階のif文でも問題なく動くか確かめるためです。

Comment: 良い書き方かどうかは分かりませんが、ヒアドキュメントを使うのはどうでしょうか https://paiza.io/projects/xQ6qNt8uQQpQEjZ5KDTZzg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

string formattingを使えば、クオートを書く回数が減ります。
https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/

また、複数行にまたがる文字列を書く場合は、トリプルクオートを使うことが可能です。
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

```py
template = """
i = {INDEX}
if i%2==0:
    if i%3==0:
        print("{INDEX}")
"""

test_str = ""
for i in range(10):
    test_str += template.format(INDEX=i)

exec(test_str)
```

Comment: 補足として，トリプルクオート中にインデントが不恰好になって困るときには [`textwrap.dedent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) が使えます．

Answer (score 3):

[google python style guide(日本語訳)](http://works.surgo.jp/translation/pyguide.html#id73)によると、

> ループ内の文字列を連結するために + や += 演算子を利用してはいけません。 文字列は イミュータブル であるため、これは不要なテンポラリーオブジェクトを作成し、実行時に線形制約クラスではなく 2 次制約クラスとなります。 その代用として、各文字を配列に入れ、ループ終了後に ‘’.join で配列を連結します (もしくは cStringIO.StringIO バッファーへの追記):

なので以下を参考に書き直すとベターです。

```
# No:
test_str = ""
for i in range(10):
    test_str += template.format(INDEX=i)

# Yes:
items = []
for i in range(10):
    items += template.format(INDEX=i)
test_str = ''.join(items)
```

ループがそんなに多くないのならば、テンポラリーオブジェクトの影響が少なくなります。ループが多いまたは、文字列のコピーに時間がかかる場合、テンポラリーオブジェクトの生成は使用メモリと計算時間に悪い影響がでます。